# Retrieving value from select list with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js 2.3.0 and I'm trying to retrieve a value set in a select list, but I can't get it to work. When I try to alert the value, I either see javascript, undefined or [object object] (depending on what I've tried).

The list is populated fine and I can set the default value, but I can't retrieve it. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the HTML for the list

```
<select data-bind='value: selectedMonth, options: $root.months, optionsText: "month"'></select>
```

And here's the JS

```
self.months = [{month: '-'},{month: '01'},{month: '02'},{month: '03'},{month: '04'},{month: '05'},{month: '06'},{month: '07'},{month: '08'},{month: '09'},{month: '10'},{month: '11'},{month: '12'}];

self.selectedMonth = ko.observable(self.months[0]);

self.submitButton = function(){

   alert(self.selectedMonth); //a bunch of JavaScript

    alert(self.selectedMonth()); //object, Object

    alert(self.months[self.selectedMonth]); //undefined

}
```

[Here is a fiddle with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/wxXxx/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second call is the one you want:

```
self.selectedMonth()
```

This unwraps the observable to the value. It's an Object, being for example:

```
{ month: "03" }
```

This is [easier to spot if you `console.log`](http://jsfiddle.net/wxXxx/3/) instead of `alert`.

In any case, to get the month value just ask for that property:

```
alert(self.selectedMonth().month);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxXxx/2/).